# How do I implement a web crawler that scrapes ad links?

Tags: python, web-crawler

To get training data, I wrote a crawler to follow the top 500 websites on Alexa with a depth of 2 and write all links found to a file. Right now, it looks for all the links in the html and writes them to a file. The problem is, the crawler misses all links to ads, some of which are located in iframes or located in CSS files. How can I change my web crawler so that it scrapes all links, including ads? The relevant code can be found below.

class Crawler(object):

```
def __init__(self, root, depth, locked=True):
    self.root = root
    self.depth = depth
    self.locked = locked
    self.host = urlparse.urlparse(root)[1]
    self.urls = []
    self.links = 0
    self.followed = 0


def crawl(self):
    #print " in crawl"
    page = Fetcher(self.root)
    q = Queue()
    #print "made fetcher"
    try:
        page.fetch()
        if page.urls == []:
            print "Error: could not fetch urls for %s" % (self.root)
            return
            #raise KeyboardInterrupt
        else: 
            target = open("output.txt", 'w')
            for url in page.urls:
                q.put(url)
                target.write((url+'\n').encode('utf-8'))
            followed = [self.root]
            target.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: could not fetch urls')
        raise KeyboardInterrupt
        '''
    q = Queue()
    target = open("output.txt", 'w')
    for url in page.urls:
        q.put(url) f
        target.write((url+'\n').encode('utf-8'))
    followed = [self.root]
    target.close()
    #print followed
    '''

    n = 0

    while True:
        try:
            url = q.get()
        except QueueEmpty:
            break

        n += 1

        if url not in followed:
            try:
                host = urlparse.urlparse(url)[1]

                if self.locked and re.match(".*%s" % self.host, host):
                    followed.append(url)
                    #print url
                    self.followed += 1
                    page = Fetcher(url)
                    page.fetch()
                    for i, url in enumerate(page):
                        if url not in self.urls:
                            self.links += 1
                            q.put(url)
                            self.urls.append(url)
                            with open("data.out", 'w') as f:
                               f.write(url)
                    if n > self.depth and self.depth > 0:
                        break
            except Exception, e:
                print "ERROR: Can't process url '%s' (%s)" % (url, e)
                print format_exc()
```

class Fetcher(object):

```
def __init__(self, url):
    self.url = url
    self.urls = []

def __getitem__(self, x):
    return self.urls[x]

def _addHeaders(self, request):
    request.add_header("User-Agent", AGENT)

def open(self):
    url = self.url
    try:
        request = urllib2.Request(url)
        handle = urllib2.build_opener()
    except IOError:
        return None
    return (request, handle)

def fetch(self):
    request, handle = self.open()
    self._addHeaders(request)
    if handle:
        try:
            content = unicode(handle.open(request).read(), "utf-8",
                    errors="replace")
            soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
            tags = soup('a')
        except urllib2.HTTPError, error:
            if error.code == 404:
                print >> sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s -> %s" % (error, error.url)
            else:
                print >> sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
            tags = []
        except urllib2.URLError, error:
            print >> sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
            tags = []
        for tag in tags:
            href = tag.get("href")
            if href is not None:
                url = urlparse.urljoin(self.url, escape(href))
                if url not in self:
                    self.urls.append(url)

def getLinks(url):
    page = Fetcher(url)
    page.fetch()
    for i, url in enumerate(page):
        print "%d. %s" % (i, url)
```

Static methods:

```
def main():
    depth =2
    file_in = []
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
    filename = "stuff.txt"
    text = open(filename)
    for line in text:
        file_in.append(line.rstrip())


    for i in file_in:
        print "Crawling %s (Max Depth: %d)" % (i, depth)
        crawler = Crawler(i, depth)
        crawler.crawl()
        print "\n".join(crawler.urls)
```

Comment: You tagged [scrapy], but you are not using it...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of advertising is delivered via asynchronous javascript executed on the page. If you're just scraping the server initial output you won't be able to obtain those others links. One method would be to use a headless browser like PhantomJS to render the html to a file then use your script on that. There are other possibilities as well.